# Crear un Thread usando la expresión Lambda en C#

Tags: c#

Hola no se porqué pero cuando intento crear un thread del siguiente modo:

```
private void Spa(int time, int id)
            => new Thread(async () =>
            {
            }).Start();
```

Me devuelve los siguientes errores:

```
; expected (CS1002) - C:\Users\Androide\Desktop\Desktop\ - Definitif\Stub\Program.cs:37,47
Identifier expected (CS1001) - C:\Users\Androide\Desktop\Desktop\- Definitif\Stub\Program.cs:38,33
Method must have a return type (CS1520) - C:\Users\Androide\Desktop\Desktop\ - Definitif\Stub\Program.cs:38,20
Invalid token '=>' in class, struct, or interface member declaration (CS1519) - C:\Users\Androide\Desktop\Desktop\ - Definitif\Stub\Program.cs:38,13
Method must have a return type (CS1520) - C:\Users\Androide\Desktop\Desktop\ - Definitif\Stub\Program.cs:40,16
```

Como podría hacer para poder usar mi thread usando la expresión lambda como solía hacer a menudo ya que me devuelve errores sintácticos.

Comment: Debe de ser por la versión del compilador, en mi maquina con vs2017 funciona correctamente.

Comment: Que versión de VS y del framework estas usando? Porque como dice @Diego658 a mi me funciona correctamente.

Comment: El error está en otro lado del código. El mensaje de error menciona que falta un  ";" pero el fragmento de código mostrado compila correctamente

Answer (score -2):

Comprobá la versión del framework.

También podrías probar invocando de la siguiente manera:

```
Thread  _thread = new Thread.....
```